# sorting obects with velocity / liferay

Tags: sorting, liferay, velocity

i have som problems with sorting a list of objects for displaying

i have this script

```
#set($dlService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalService"))
#set($dlTypeService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryTypeLocalService"))
#set($dlVersionService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileVersionLocalService"))


#if (!$entries.isEmpty())
    <div class="row-fluid site">
        <div class="">
            <div class="grid" id="bubble-container">
                <div style="width: 50%;" class="grid-sizer"></div>
                #foreach ($entry in $entries)
                    #**
                     * GET DATA
                     *#
                    #set($fileEntry = $dlService.getDLFileEntryByUuidAndCompanyId($entry.getUuid(), $entry.getCompanyId()))
                    #set($fileEntryTypeId = $fileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId())
                    #set($fileEntryType = $dlTypeService.getDLFileEntryType($fileEntryTypeId))
                    #set($dlFileVersion = $dlVersionService.getLatestFileVersion($fileEntry.getUserId(), $fileEntry.getFileEntryId()))
                    #set($fieldsMap = $fileEntry.getFieldsMap($dlFileVersion.getFileVersionId()))

                    #set($isDark=false)
                    #set($Ueberschrift = "")
                    #set($URL = "")
                    #set($Teaser = "")

                    #foreach ($key in $fieldsMap.keySet())
                        #set($URL = $fieldsMap.get($key).get("url").getValue())
                        #set($Ueberschrift = $fieldsMap.get($key).get("ueberschrift").getValue())
                        #set($Teaser = $fieldsMap.get($key).get("teaser").getValue())
                        #set($isDark = $fieldsMap.get($key).get("schwarzerHintergrund").getValue())
                    #end


                    <div style="width: 50%; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;" class="grid-item">
                        #set($imageURL = $dlUtil.getPreviewURL($entry, $entry.getFileVersion(), $themeDisplay, ""))
                        #set ($additionalCss = "")
                        #if ($isDark)
                            #set ($additionalCss = "black")
                        #end
                        <a href="$URL">
                            <div class="bubble $additionalCss">
                                <h2>$Ueberschrift</h2>
                                <p>$Teaser</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bubble-icon">
                                    <img src="$imageURL"/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                #end
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
#end
```

now i want to sort the objects in the outer foreach loop

i've read something about it at https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html but i'm not ne able to expand the script and sort the objects
it must be something like

#foreach ($entry in $entries_sort.Sort($entries,"getUuid"))

does anyone have a hint for me?

best regards

Answer (score 2):

In Velocity you have available `$sortTool` which provides sort method. Example of usage:

```
#foreach ($curEntry in $sortTool.sort($entries, 'entryId:asc'))
    $curEntry
#end
```